# Ionic v4- Why does my get function return undefined?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to get my location so to start I tried to save my latitude and longitude but my declared variable never returns anything.

Here is my code:

```
public device_location: any = {};

constructor(private geolocation: Geolocation) {
this.setGeolocation();
this.getGeolocation();
}

setGeolocation(){
   this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
       // resp.coords.latitude
       this.device_location.latitude = resp.coords.latitude;
       this.device_location.longitude = resp.coords.longitude;
       console.log( this.device_location.longitude);
       }).catch((error) => {
   console.log('Error getting location', error);
 });

 let watch = this.geolocation.watchPosition();
 watch.subscribe((data) => {
// data can be a set of coordinates, or an error (if an error occurred).
// data.coords.latitude
// data.coords.longitude
 });
}

getGeolocation(){
    console.log( JSON.stringify(this.device_location) );
    return this.device_location;
}
```

and here is the output:

> 123.45600
>   {}

Answer (score 0):

Remove this from constructor :

```
this.getGeolocation();
```

and call it like this in this method :

```
setGeolocation(){
this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
   // resp.coords.latitude
   this.device_location.latitude = resp.coords.latitude;
   this.device_location.longitude = resp.coords.longitude;

   this.getGeolocation();



   console.log( this.device_location.longitude);
   }).catch((error) => {
   console.log('Error getting location', error);
});
```